# how to switch between left and right css rules using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

I have used css class, for example

```
.dropdown-menu{right:0;}
```

Now I just need to replace css property at client side, that is

```
.dropdown-menu{left:0;}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot modify CSS class attributes that have already been parsed by the client browser. Your best option is to create a new class, and assign it via JavaScript/jQuery, or otherwise override the CSS. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
$('.dropdown-menu').css({
  'right':'auto',
  'left': '0'
 });
```

Set the default value for `right` rule and the one you want for `left`

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this

```
$(".dropdown-menu").css('right', '').css( 'left','0' )
```

---

try out pure javascript solution

```
   document.getElementsByClassName(".dropdown-menu").style.removeAttribute('right');
   $(".dropdown-menu")..css( 'left','0' )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `removeClass()` and `addClass()` from JQuery if you set up specific classes for what you need:

```
$('#MyElement').removeClass('rightClass');
$('#MyElement').addClass('leftClass');
```

Using `$('#MyElement').removeClass();` will remove all classes.

So using the OP's example, you'd have:

```
.dropdown-menu-right {right:0;}
.dropdown-menu-left {left:0;}
```

Then in the JQuery swap them out i.e:

```
$('#MyDropDownMenu').removeClass('dropdown-menu-right');
$('#MyDropDownMenu').addClass('dropdown-menu-left');
```

This saves you having to worry about styling existing outside your stylesheet(s) making it easier/simpler to make changes in the future.

edited to include working example of this in action:

http://jsfiddle.net/CatmanDoes/e213jza6/

---

JQuery - [removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) , [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/)

Comment: Sorry brother I think that is not good, Because I just need to change only one CSS property and also the class come from bootstrap core file. may be It'll affect other things

Comment: Well you should never modify the bootstrap files, you should create another stylesheet and load that in after the bootstrap ones. That way should you need you can override the standard bootstrap ones with ease.  Think to yourself, in 6 months (or whatever) when someone (you?) has to make some design changes, where are they going to look for CSS modifications? In the stylesheets right?

Comment: Okay brother I'll try and let you know

Comment: Well first up Bootstrap has this done for you already, there is a pull-right class in the library so there's no need to add or change any existing stylesheet code. Here is a working example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/CatmanDoes/e213jza6/